# git svn ignore paths use ignore file

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, gitignore

I am converting a svn repo to a git repo and we have a number of binary files that have been checked in over the years that shouldn't have, along with images and other files, I don't really want these files present in the git repo taking up space.

I have played around with git-svn to convert the repo and have used its -ignorepaths property but I'd like to be able to feed a list into the ignore paths rather than having to specify a ignorepaths for each pattern/directory I want to exclude, if I could use a svnignore/gitignore file during the conversion that would take out this junk that would be even better.

Is there a way to do this or do I just have to bit the bullet and specify each pattern/path individually?

EDIT: updated question to be more clear as to what I was asking

Comment: It probably does but i was really just using that as an example, I'd like to have a whole heap of extensions/paths easily

Comment: I think there is no easy way out to this - you have to list what you want to ignore - either but creative regex or just list them all

Answer (score 2):

Subversion is a bit complicated there if you're used to git. `svn:ignore` is a property that works on a per folder basis. In a particular folder, you can only ignore specific files or immediate subfolders.
You can pass a file to the command that sets the ignore properties on DIRECTORY and you could also pass the .gitignore file to it with:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F .gitignore DIRECTORY
```

But for the above mentioned reason, really practical portions in the .gitignore like `*/build` will have no effect in Subversion.

The only thing you can do is make use of the `--depth` argument for `svn propset` for instance if you pass `--depth immediates`, it will set the property for DIRECTORY and every immediate subfolder. There are also ways to specify the depth or just make it inifite - I think TAB completion works there or look into the help.

There is still a major drawback though: Everytime you add a folder that contains files you want to ignore, you would have to run the `svn propset` command again.

Comment: unfortunately I dont think this is what I'm looking for, I'm wanting to convert a svn repo to a git repo and take out some of the crud that was added along the way as if it never happened

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that `git svn` does **not** take any notice of the contents of `.gitignore` when fetching from Subversion, regardless of whether the `.gitignore` has been checked in to the repo.

The solution, as stated in your question, is to use `--ignore-paths` with the `git svn clone`. Once you've done this, it gets added to the `.git/config` file so you don't have to keep specifying it each time you fetch content.

Converting an existing `.gitignore` file into a Perl regular expression for using with `--ignore-paths` isn't as complicated as it might seem since you can *or* terms together.

For example:

```
/[Dd]ebug/|^rootfile\.txt$|\.bak$
```

excludes `debug` folders anywhere in the path, the specific file `rootfile.txt` in the root of the repo, and all `*.bak` files.

## Tips:

- an expression that ends with a forward slash will exclude the content of the named folder but not the folder itself
- `^` matches the root of the repository and paths from the root don't start with a slash
- you can use [lookaround expressions in the regexes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) if needed, e.g. excluding all `Bin` folders *unless* they are preceded by some particular directory

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert svn:ignore to .gitignore or vice versa, you can use [SubGit](http://subgit.com) instead of git-svn, which performs this conversion automatically. The conversion command in the simplest configuration looks like:

```
$ subgit install path/to/svn/repository
```

Comment: Thats not really what I'm looking for, I want to create a git repository using a git-ignore to filter out files while the repo is created

Comment: gitignore has no relation to that, you question is misleading a bit. To filter files you may use "svnadmin dump" + svndumpfilter/svndumptool + "svnadmin load" or an utility by me --- svnkitfilter (you can patch it to filter whatever you want) --- to filter something at SVN side, "git filter-branch" to filter on Git side or --ignore-paths option of git-svn

Comment: yes I was looking for a way to feed git-svn a list of options for ignore-path rather than listing each individually, or something that would achieve the same thing basically

Comment: I have updated the question to try and clarify what i was looking for